# BERT embeddings for entire sentences vs. verbs

Tags: nlp, word-embedding, bert-language-model

First off, I am drawing upon assumption that majority of the semantic *value* of the sentence is mediated by verbs that connect the subject and the object of said verb. I am aware that I simplify a bit here as there can be multiple verbs and such. But abstracting from that, I'd be curious whether it applies that a BERT generated embedding vector for entire sentence, say **"Two halves make a whole"** would be measurably more similar to an embedding vector for a singular verb like **"make"** as compared to say a vector for verb **"eat"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your "question", if I were you I would try to do a practical test. For an easy way to use bert for sentence embeddings, check this [repo](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers): it is summarily simple to use.

Once you have the embedding vectors, you can use any [similarity function](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/clustering/similarity/measuring-similarity) to validate your hypothesis.

However for what is my (limited) experience, I think that the vector of "make" is more similar than that of "eat" also only because "make" is present in the other sentence and therefore contributes to the ambedding of the sentence.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, a bit after writing this question I have done precisely what you suggest, and it does seem either my hypothesis was incorrect or I have used the metric (euclidean distance) incorrectly. So comparing sentences like I indicated in my question to different verbs actually did produce results within the margin of error.

Comment: Great! I intuitively would have used the cosene similarity between the two embedding vectors (that of the sentence with one verb and then with the other. Finally compare the two results)

Comment: Nor the cosine similarity was indicating a sentence would be more similar to a verb contained in it than to completely unrelated word. I've calculated euclidean distance, cosine similarity for both [CLS] outputs of the Bert encoder, which should to my understanding somewhat capture the meaning of the entire sentence, as well as averages over the rest of the outs for each token, mostly just to check, again with statistically insignificant differences.